# Google Reader - Keeping Read Item state in Sync

Tags: html, http, google-app-engine, google-reader

What is the best way to manage cached articles when it comes to 
keeping the read state/unread state in sync?  Is there a property 
inside the article feed that will tell me the state of the item?  I'm 
trying to figure out how to keep the read state in sync, and if I need 
to do a comparison of every cached article to the one on Google 
Reader.

So far I've only been requesting unread items, so I exclude anything 
that's already been marked as read.  However, I might have some cached 
articles unread on the client that have been marked as read on Google 
Reader.  Those articles won't be downloaded again, but I'd like to 
perhaps do a check on launch of each unread article, to see if it 
should still be displayed as unread.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reader API, so I believe you're stuck with re-fetching the 'unread items' feed repeatedly, and removing any items that are no longer present in it. As far as seeing the status of items that are too old to be in the feed, I'm not sure if there's a practical way to do that at all.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but bear in mind that, given the lack of an API, there's no way for you to mark an item as read, either.